# Combine three regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to combine the following three expressions into one regex?

```
name = re.sub(r'\s?\(\w+\)', '',name) # John Smith (ii) --> John Smith
name = re.sub(r'\s?(Jr.|Sr.)$','', name, flags=re.I) # John Jr. --> John
name = re.sub(r'".+"\s?', '', name) # Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson --> Dwayne Johnson
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use grouping and pipe:

```
re.sub(r'(\s?\(\w+\))|(s?(Jr.|Sr.))|(".+"\s?)', '', name)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sX5uV9/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain an efficient (and a working most of the time) pattern simply separating your patterns with a pipe is a bad idea. You must reconsider what you want to do with your pattern and rewrite it from the begining.

```
p = re.compile(r'["(js](?:(?<=\b[js])r\.|(?<=\()\w+\)|(?<=")[^"]*")\s*', re.I)
text = p.sub('', text).rstrip()
```

This is a good opportunity to be critical about what you have previously written:

- starting a pattern with an optional character `\s?` is slow because each position in the string must be tested with and without this character. So this is better to catch the optional whitespace at the end and to trim the string after. *(in all cases you need to trim the result, even if you decide to catch the optional whitespace at the begining)*
- the pattern to find quoted parts is false and inefficient (when it works), because you use a dot with a greedy quantifier, so if there are two quoted parts in the same line *(note that the dot doesn't match newlines)* all the content between will be matched too. It's better to use a negated character class that doesn't contain the quote: `"[^"]*"` *(note: this can be improved to deal with escaped quotes inside the quotes)*
- the pattern for `Jr.` and `Sr.` is false too, to match a literal `.` you need to escape it. Aside from
  that, the pattern is too imprecise because it doesn't check if there are other word characters before. It will match for example a sentence that ends with "USSR." or any substrings that contain "jr." or "sr.". *(to be fully rigorous, you must check if there is a whitespace or the start of the string before, but a simple word boundary should suffice most of the time)*

Now how to build your alternation:

The order can be important, in particular if the subpatterns are not mutualy exclusive. For example, if you have the subpatterns `a+b` and `a+`, if you write `a+|a+b` all the `b` preceded by an `a` will never match because the first branch succeeds before. But for your example there is not this kind of problems.

As an aside, if you know that one of the branches has more chances to succeed put it at the first position in the alternation.

You know the searched substring starts with one of these characters: `"`, `(`, `j`, `s`. In this case why not begining the pattern with `["(js]` that avoids to test each branch of the pattern for all positions in the string.
Then, since the first character is already consumed, you only need to check with a lookbehind which of these characters has been matched for each branch.

With these small improvements you obtain a much faster pattern.